# Horizontally and vertically centered iframe with aspect ratio 16:9 that uses as much screen estate as possible without being cropped anywhere

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, responsive-design

**Requirements**:

- The HTML: The iframe **HAS** to be inside of a containing div. See code down below.
- The CSS: The container should be able to have **ANY** valid `width` and `height` using the `vw` and `vh` viewport units. Se code down below.
- Yes, the `width` and `height` `HAS` to be in `vw` and `vh`.
- The static video preview image should **NEVER** be cropped.
- The static video preview image should **NOT** have any black bars above and below (letterboxing).
- The static video preview image should **NOT** have any black bars to the left or to the right (pillarboxing).
- The static video preview image should use as much space estate as possible inside the div that contains it.
- The static video preview image should **ALWAYS** keep its aspect ratio of 16:9.
- Scrollbars should **NEVER** appear.
- The static video preview image should be centered vertically as well as horizontally inside the div that contains it.
- Responsive Web Design.

When resizing the browser or viewport all of the above requirements should be fulfilled.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container {
   width:90vw;
   height:50vh;
}
```

Comment: if you use the video tag, then you can style it, here you can only style iframe but nothing loaded inside.

Comment: The requirements require an iframe (YouTube video).

Comment: okay, what have you tried with iframe style ?

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum requirement size exceeded

Comment: Keeping a constant aspect ratio of 16:9 without image being cropped or having letterboxing/pillerboxing is impossible once you start resizing window to various widths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JavaScript, you can listen for the `resize` event, which fires whenever the browser's window changes shape. Then, with some simple algebra you can calculate the dimensions of the iframe based on the dimensions of the container. Here is a demo that shows all of the requirements.

```js
"use strict";

var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var frame = container.querySelector('iframe');

function resizeVideo() {
 frame.width = frame.height = 0;

 var width = container.offsetWidth;
 var height = container.offsetHeight;

 if (height * (16 / 9) <= width) {
  frame.height = height;
  frame.width = height * (16 / 9);
 } else {
  frame.width = width;
  frame.height = width * (9 / 16);
 }
}

window.addEventListener('load', resizeVideo);
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeVideo);
```

```css
.container {
 width: 90vw;
 height: 50vh;

 display: table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BKhZvubRYy8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: You're definitely on to something here. The javascript code looks clean with minimum lines of code. The only thing that I don't like is the display, text-align and vertical-align properties. Could it be done using flexbox instead perhaps?

Comment: @PussInBoots: I admit don't know much about flexbox, but yes, there are many popular ways to center an element in its container and this should work with most of them.

Answer (score 6):

Same solution, but no extra markup for keeping the ratio.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Erik_J/3gbzxof2/) with same comments totally not needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fully Container Centred Iframe</title>
<meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
<style>
.container {
    display:table-cell; /* (specs: omitted table parts, the browser will insert mandatory elements in the dom tree) */
    position:relative;
    padding:; /* optional, margins ignored */
    width:100vw; /* any value */
    height:1vh; /* will expand by the :before element */
    overflow:hidden; /* hide eventual black bars */
    background:tan; /* bg-colors just for demo testing */
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.container:before {
    display:block;
    padding-top:56%; /* keeps the 16/9 ratio for the AP */
    height:0;
    background:red;
    content:"\a0";
}
.container iframe {
    position:absolute; /* to be ratio consistent */
    top:-.5%;
    left:-.5%; /* overflow eventual black bars */
    border:0;
    width:101%; /* grow some to avoid thinner black bars */
    height:101%;
    overflow:hidden; /* for html5 browsers the html attribute is depreciated */
    background:gold;
}
</style>
</head><body>

<div class="container">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src=""></iframe>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: That doesn't keep the video from exceeding `50vh` (given as the container's height in the question).

Comment: @rvighne, Yes, you are right. And if it's really necessary there are several options to apply a fix for an eventual height ruled somewhere else. The easiest is to make the 1vh important, other options need extra markup.   I should have asked PussinBoots if his example ment the arbitrary height was mandatory, the 90/50 is'nt exactly 16/9, but I kind of hoped he would notice the small vh values in my examples and comment. ...I was too lazy I guess. :)

Comment: @rvighne, If you look at my first post below you can see one of the options to allow any height on the "container" and still have the desired ratio, but it requires extra markup. (Too slow to edit my comment, newbe here.)

Comment: When I resize the viewport vertically the youtube preview image gets cropped. Width and height of the container div can be of any value as long as it is specified in vw for the width property and vh for the height property.

Answer (score 3):

if you want Responsive use

```
.container, iframe {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting but the width for the .container div needs to be in vw as per the requirement.

Comment: If you use a static width/height It not will be Responsive.

Comment: It is not static. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: oh . Thanks for share the link.

Answer (score 3):

```
.container {
    width:90vw;
    height:50vh;
}
.container iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Seems to work quite nicely in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1q10L7hj/

Comment: The video is cropped as soon as the page loads.

Comment: @PussInBoots Hmm, for me it only cropped the preview image, but I when playing the video it scaled down without cropping, even on mobile. Removing the `height: 100%` will also remove the black bars from the top and bottom, but I guess that's not what you mean.

Comment: The preview image should not be cropped.

Comment: @PussInBoots loose the iframe, it is xdomain, so you cant modify the style of the content.

Comment: This doesn't force the 16:9 aspect ratio

Comment: It crops the preview to a wider container's current height. Then the video has its default ratio, limited by the lesser length of the container resulting in black bars, horizontal or vertical when the container change size. The default scrollbar shows in both preview and play regardless of size.

Comment: Why has this answer been upvoted? It does not meet the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

why don't you just use the calc method to get the aspect ratio width you are wanting?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
<style>

$width = 80vw;

.container {
    width: $width;
    height: calc(($width/16) * 9);
    position: relative;
}
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(+50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(+50%, -50%);
}

</style>
```

then you can change the width of it anywhere and apply whatever positioning you want on the container div and the iframe with follow suit

Comment: This does not cover all of the requirements. Try out your code in codepen or in a similar service and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Au contraire mr @PussInBoots

http://codepen.io/calebswank11/pen/RRpMJV

supplies the same solution but much cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Could you explain why 80vw is used?

Comment: I only used 80vw to visually show the video changing outside the constraints of the window width. you can change that variable to anything and it should work the same.

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten the result you wanted, I however had to add an extra `div` as the parent of the `.container` class. This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djburkhart/gjny8rkh/) should work for users on chrome (*Windows desktop version*) however when I tried to use the same fiddle on Edge and IE11 I found that it would create the undesired letter-box effect due to the image cover zooming too far out.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
      <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YL9RetC0ook" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
      </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

.container,iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I am not sure if this works for Firefox, so perhaps if you have Firefox you can try it on my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djburkhart/gjny8rkh/). However for Chrome (*at the very least*) this should be the solution you where looking for as stated by the requirements you listed.

Comment: In both Firefox and Chromium in Linux It crops the preview to a wider container's current height. Then the video isn't cropped but limited by the lesser length of the container resulting in black bars, horizontal or vertical when the container change. (The `scrolling` attribute is mistyped so the default scrollbar show.)

Comment: This answer does not seem to correctly work on any browser and should be ignored, however if you are looking for the correct work I have updated my JSFiddle to reflect @Erik.J fiddle. If you wish for the correct answer please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38013834/2174825 post.

Comment: Thanks for posting but the extra wrapper div, letterboxing issue and browser incompatibilitie makes it very difficult to accept this one as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the table-cell display could solve this. Just apply it on the container so the iframe is the content

According to specs the browser will insert dummy elements where it needs to render the cell correctly and fully centre and to contain its content and if it need, grow with it.

The requirements: I think some of them is beyond the scope of your question, they will also depend on what is loaded in the iframe, out of control of this container document. My suggested code is simple, but I believe it meets all requirements possible for the iframe parent and still be crossbrowser friendly.

The forbidden black bars and the mandatory aspect ratio could still be at fault in the loaded document. If you can't control whats loaded, the last option might be the "srcdoc" and "seamless" attributes, but that would exclude e.g. all IE versions.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Erik_J/aay55pny/) with some comments totally not needed. Hope the edit below solves the case.

Anyway, I had fun! Thanks! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fully Container Centred Iframe</title>
<meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
<style>
.container {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:;
    width:100vw;
    height:20vh;
    background:tan;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.container .ratio{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56%;
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.container iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:-1%;
    left:-1%;
    border:0;
    width:102%;
    height:102%;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
</head><body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio">
        <iframe scrolling="no" src=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: @PussInBoots, I think all your requirements are met now. If you could find time to check if I have understood correctly your question. It was fun. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks but there is an extra div and also this looks like a variant of the padding-bottom hack which isn't enough.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a JavaScript window.resize listener to solve this kind of an issue. Cannot write code today cause I have a pretty tight schedule, but I'll try writing an algo:

- On window resize, compute window width (wW) and window height (wH);
- Determine container width (cW) as per wW (say cW = wW-10 to get almost all the width available - you can omit the -10 if you want);
- Determine container height (cH) as per cW computed above: cH = cW * 9 / 16;
- Now, if cH > wH (i.e. the container is not fitting into the screen vertically because it is too wide), we should revise cW as per available window height. In this case, cH = wH-10 (to get almost all the vertical space available - again, you can omit the -10 if you want) and then **cW = wH * 16 / 9**;
- You should have a valid cW and cH now to make you container fit into the window without going out of the screen and you can apply it to the container.
- To center the container to the screen, use **position: absolute, left: 50%; top: 50%;** in your CSS. When you update the cW and cH, also update **margin-left: -(cW/2); margin-top: -(cH/2);**

This is the concept - you can improvise as per your needs. I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you post an example?